# Obtener el número recomendado de topics de un modelo LDA usando pyspark.ml

Tags: python, apache-spark, nlp, pyspark, databricks

He entrenado un modelo LDA usando pyspark para clasificar textos por temas, probando diferentes valores para **`K`**. Sin embargo, para validar que el **`K`** seleccionado es correcto quisiera obtener el equivalente a CoherenceModel de gesim, pero no consigo su equivalente en **pyspark.ml**.

Después del preprocesamiento de texto, mi dataframe tiene esta pinta (una columna de ID y otra con los tokens limpios de opiniones de clientes):

```
tokenizedText.show(truncate=True, n=5)

+------------+--------------------+
|          ID|              Tokens|
+------------+--------------------+
|0000qaqdWUAQ|[limpieza, mala, ...|
|0000qaqe2UAA|[transporte, deja...|
|0000qasxUUAQ|          [correcto]|
|0000qatEJUAY|              [bien]|
|0000qaqwMUAQ|[experiencia, agr...|
+------------+--------------------+
```

Y el modelo básico es algo como esto:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import IDF, HashingTF, Tokenizer, StopWordsRemover, CountVectorizer
from pyspark.ml.clustering import LDA, LDAModel

counter = CountVectorizer(inputCol="Tokens", outputCol="term_frequency", minDF=5)
counterModel = counter.fit(tokenizedText)   
vectorizedLaw = counterModel.transform(trainingData)

idf = IDF(inputCol="term_frequency", outputCol="tf_idf")
tfidfLaw = idf.fit(vectorizedLaw).transform(vectorizedLaw)

lda = LDA(k=7, maxIter=50, featuresCol="tf_idf", seed=1234)
model = lda.fit(tfidfLaw)
```

Con esta configuración, obtengo:

```
model.logLikelihood(tfidfLaw)
Out[295]: -17745244.739330653

model.logPerplexity(tfidfLaw)
Out[296]: 7.63661972904619
```

He revisado las opciones de model, pero no encuentro el equivalente al **`CoherenceModel`** de **`gensim`**, para comparar los diferente modelos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Conozco la solución con **`gensim`**, he encontrado varios ejemplos muy útiles como este [evaluate-topic-model-in-python-latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda](https://towardsdatascience.com/evaluate-topic-model-in-python-latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda-7d57484bb5d0) (ver el titulo Compute Model Perplexity and Coherence Score y el Hyperparameter Tuning), he convertido mi dataframe a un **`pandas`** df para aplicar esta solución y hallar el número correcto de topics, pero por el tamaño de mis datos, la solución es inviable, después de mucho tiempo de ejecución, he recibido este error:

```
Internal error, sorry. Attach your notebook to a different cluster or restart the current cluster.
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779)
    at shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.doFinishConnect(SelectorManager.java:355)
    at shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.processConnect(ManagedSelector.java:232)
    at shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.access$1400(ManagedSelector.java:62)
    at shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.processSelected(ManagedSelector.java:543)
    at shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:401)
    at shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produceTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:360)
    at shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:184)
    at shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:367)
    at shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:782)
    at shaded.v9_4.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:914)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Estoy ejecutando sobre Databricks Runtime Version 6.5 ML (includes Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11), Driver Type: 15.3 GB Memory, 2 Cores, 1 DBU.

Conocéis una opción apropiada para obtener el número recomendado de topics para el modelo LDA usando **`pyspark.ml`**?, o un workaround para usar el Coherence Score de **`gensim`** evitando mis problemas en la ejecución?.